# how capture and register video automatically with ionic and cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I need to build an application where user can with one button recorder video of 20 seconds without having to click for start recording and click for register.
With on click on button the application opens camera, record, register, and close camera automatically.
I tried with `Cordova-plugin-media, but when the camera is open we have to click for recording and register.
Have you a solution with this plugin or another ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the plugin https://github.com/mihnsen/phonegap-auto-record-video/

here is the js code sample you can use.

```
window.plugins.autorecordvideo.record(function (file) {        
    console.log(file);
    Uploads.upload(file.fullPath); // uploads file to server

}, function (error) {
    alert('auto record error');
    console.log(error);
}, {duration: 10} //video record  duration 
);
```